# How to calculate the order of the subgroup?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

Given a curve with points over GF(p), a subgroup of prime order `q` and a co-factor h.

How do I calculate the size of `q` which is also the modulus?

I was thinking q = p/h

Comment: Dupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40726/how-is-the-order-of-a-point-calculated-for-elliptic-curves-over-gfp and more linked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Schoof's algorithm on the curve parameters to find $qh$, and divide by $h$.

The size $p$ of the coordinate field is only required, by Hasse's theorem, to be *near* $qh$, within a factor of a square root: $|qh - (p + 1)| \leq 2 \sqrt p$.  Consequently, $p/h$ may be *near* $q$ but is not *equal* to $q$ except in anomalous curves in which ECDLP is easily solved by additive transfers as described by [Smart](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001459900052) ([preprint](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/97/HPL-97-128.pdf)), [Araki–Satoh](https://rikkyo.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=9910&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=49), and [Semaev](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1998-67-221/S0025-5718-98-00887-4/S0025-5718-98-00887-4.pdf) (the ‘Smart-ASS’ attack).

For example, Curve25519's coordinate field is $\operatorname{GF}(2^{255} - 19)$, and its order $2^{255} + 221938542218978828286815502327069187944 = qh$ where $q = 2^{252} + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$ and $h = 8$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why I cannot just divide by the co-factor?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends: divide *what* by the cofactor?  You need to know the number of points on the curve (and while it'll be close to $p$, it won't be exactly $p$)

Comment: Oh, I was referring to do `p/h` . TBC I have the order of the basefield `p` already

Comment: @poncho To rephrase, given a group `p`, how do I find the largest subgroup?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends: you find the order of the group (Schoof's algorithm), and then factor it.  This latter part is easier than it sounds; we only use curves that have orders that are easy to factor (qh, for a large prime q, and a small integer h)

Comment: @poncho Would the order of GF(p) be p, if p is prime?

Comment: @WeCanBeFriends: do you mean the order of an elliptic curve based on $GF(p)$; no, in general, it wouldn't (but again, it would be close).  Do you mean the order of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?  No, that'd be $p-1$.  Do you mean the order of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p^+$?  Yes, that would be (however, that group isn't typically used in cryptography, as things like the 'discrete log' problem (modular division) is easy